# Question on the definition of graded rings

Tags: linear-algebra

the most common definition of a graded ring $R$ is that $R$ has (as an abelian group) a decomposition as $R=\oplus_{i\in I} R_i$ where $R_i$ are abelian groups and the $\oplus$ denotes the direct sum of them. Additionally one requires that $R_i R_j\subset R_{i+j}$. Here my first question arises:

1) In $R_i R_j\subset R_{i+j}$ the multiplication is not clear to me as the $R_i,R_j$ are just abelian groups.

2) I often read that any element $x\in R$ has a unique  decomposition as $x=\sum_{i\in I} x_i$ for $x_i\in R_i$. Again this is not clear to me because any element of $R$ is a priori of the form $(x_i)_{i\in I}$. The above form is only obvious if all $R_i$ are disjoint. But is this always the case?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A graded ring is a ring $R$ such that $R=\bigoplus_{i\in I}R_i$ where the $R_i$'s are abelian groups (for a sum $+$) such that $R_iR_j\subset R_{i+j}$. The definition says that $R$ is a ring, hence there is a multiplication, it follows that one can multiply elements of $R_i$ with elements of $R_j$ for all $i$ and $j$. Thus $R_iR_j\subset R_{i+j}$ makes sense. The second statement follows from the definition of direct sum (of groups).

Comment: An element of $R_i$ is an element of an abelian group, but not an element of the ring. The elements of the ring are sequences $(x_i)$. Hence there is no multiplication.

Comment: No, by definition $R_i\subset R$ and $R$ is a ring.

Comment: Look at the standard example $k[X]$, this is graded by the degree. Hence $R_i=\left\{\lambda X^i\mid \lambda\in k\right\}$ is an abelian group for $+$, but you do know how to multiply $X^i$ and $X^j$.

Comment: Be sure to accept an answer if you are satisfied with it. If you don't understand it yet I will explain it in more detail.

Comment: I still have to questions. 1) You say that $R_i\subset R$. Do you implicitely embed $R_i$ into the direct sum as $0\oplus...\oplus 0\oplus R_i\oplus 0\oplus...$? 2) Can you be more explicit why every element can be written as a sum of homogenous elements? For example I can take the direct sum $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ and cannot write an element $(z_1,z_2)$ as $z_1+z_2$. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, $R_i\subset R$ after identification with the direct sum. And this immediately solves your second question, as $z_1\in \mathbb{Z}=R_1$ is identified with $(z_1,0)$ and $z_2\in \mathbb{Z}=R_2$ is identified with $(0,z_2)$.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. For the example of $k[X]$ it is all very natural. For $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ I find it strange to identify, because the identification is not well-defined: $z\in R_1=R_2$ gets mapped to $(z,0)$ and $(0,z)$ by random...

Comment: @user818182: I suggest treating $R = \bigoplus\limits_{i \in I} R_i$ as an **internal** direct sum; i.e., the $R_i$ are subgroups of $R$ that are linearly disjoint and whose sum is $R$. This way, you don't have to identify anything, since $R_i \subseteq R$ already holds. But if you want to allow external direct sums, you need to replace the condition $R_i R_j \subseteq R_{i+j}$ by $S_i S_j \subseteq S_{i+j}$, where $S_k$ denotes the image of $R_k$ in the direct sum $R$.